# Preventing a discord bot from executing a command in a user prompt

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I need some help/suggestion to prevent a discord bot from executing a command in a user prompt.

My bot currently has a feature that prompts the user a question, and it'll add whatever the user's answer is to the database. The problem that I'm trying to solve is, currently the user's able to enter a bot command as an answer, and the bot would both execute that command and take that as an answer to add to the database.

A very quick example to show how problematic this can get:

```
User: ?question
```

```
Bot: Cats or Dogs?
```

```
User: ?question
```

```
Bot: "?question" have been added to the database
```

```
Bot: Cats or Dogs?
```

I don't have a problem with the bot adding the command to the database, because that's what the user entered (it might be relevant for the user to enter a bot command there), but I don't want the bot to execute that command.

Right now I have 2 vague ideas to solve this (I don't know whether or not any of this will be valid):

- I need to turn the user's answer into an "answer" type variable where the bot can't use it to search for commands, but can still use it to upload to the database and fetch from it and display in a list of answers. Although I don't know if this can be executed before the bot starts to search for the command.
- I need to somehow change how this system of question & answer works.

Note: Currently my bot detects a command by slicing the first bit of the user's message `.slice(config.prefix.length)`

Any help or suggestion will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a command handler employed? This would be an easy modification.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some answers to your question:

- **The bot takes in a command as an answer.**
  If you ever change your mind, you can disallow this by simply allowing only a few selected responses ("cat" or "dog") or disallowing commands that start with a `?`.
- **The command is executed if a command was used as an answer.**
  This is because you check if the message is a command down the line, somewhere in your code. Not only does the bot recognize the user's message as a valid answer, but it also recognizes that it fulfills the prefix you set and thus it runs the command.
  If you have a flag that indicates that the user's next response is an answer to the Q&A question, then you can check if that flag is active before executing the command. For example:

```js
// Assume that the user's ID is in this array after they
// requested to answer a Q&A question.
var usersAwaitingResponse = [];
...
client.on("message", function(message) {
    if (usersAwaitingResponse.includes(message.author.id)) {
        // take in the answer and then end the function by calling "return;"
    } else {
        // check if the message was a command and act accordingly
    }
});
```

**Prefix Checking**
Lastly, I recommend that you check if a message is a command by using `.startsWith(config.prefix)` on the message text. If you want the user to only input allowed characters after the prefix, then you can use a regular expression. Either method saves time and memory rather than slicing the string. An example of those can be seen below:

```js
// using "startsWith"
function checkIfCommand(message) {
    return message.content.startsWith(config.prefix);
}

// using a regular expression
function checkIfCommand(message) {
    /**
     * If all the matches are fulfilled, the test passes:
     *
     * ^ - The match should be at the beginning of the string.
     * ${config.prefix} - The prefix (interpolated into the string).
     * [A-Z0-9]+ - match as much characters that are A to Z or 0 to 9
     * \s? - Match a whitespace character (if there is one)
     * "gi" - global, case insensitive
    **/
    return new RegExp(`^${config.prefix}[A-Z]+\s?`, "gi").test(message.content);
}
```